# What is the Java's best equivalent to Javascript's OR?

Tags: java, java-8

In Javascript I can do the following to get a value according to their respective order of appearance in the assignment..

```
var myString = source1 || source2 || source3 || source4 || source5;
```

If any of the sources has value, it will be assigned to myString. If all sources have value, it will take the first one.

In Java, the `java.util.Optional` seems limited to only just `Optional.of("value").orElse( "another" )` and it cannot chain anymore as the the return of orElse() is already a string.

Comment: What's the type of `source` in Java? `Optional`?

Comment: What if no sources have value? What do you want?

Comment: Assume it's guaranteed that at least one of them has a value, `source1.orElse(source2.orElse(source3.get()))` will work.

Answer (score 6):

I would probably use something simple like:

```
public static <T> T first(T... values) {
    for (T v : values) {
        if (v != null) return v;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This might be more efficient way but the performance really does not matter in this case.

Answer (score 4):

While it can be argued that there are lot of approaches, I prefer the following approach:

```
Integer i = Stream.of(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 1, 2)
                  .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filter out null's
                  .findFirst().orElse(10); // default to 10
// Objects::nonNull is same as e -> e != null
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Could be enhanced by using [`Objects::nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Instead of the `.get()` on the Optional I suggest using a default value like `.orElse(null)` if all elements in the stream are null.

Comment: @Flown Ofcourse a method reference would even work but lambda is more understandable :)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat That's is really a matter of taste and IMHO `nonNull` is more readable than `x != null`.

Comment: @Flown Sure it is :) Even I like method references but when I started learning about it, it used to confuse me alot. That is why I intentionally wrote a lambda.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat yet another reason to write a method reference, to get better at that, especially here, where it is pretty easy to figure out...

Comment: @Eugene Yeah, updated. But the only problem with method reference here is we won't be able to filter other values such as `e -> e != 1`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat good thing you don't have do it here, right? ;)

Comment: @Eugene Right :D

Answer (score 2):

Just to post a non streams alternative to the stream api

If you have only very small sets of strings you want to compare against non empty values, you might want to save the overhead of initializing the streams, the lambdas etc.. what happens under the hood.

You can use the three dots `...` to indicate "any number of arguments" which in your method will effectively be turned into a `String[] arguments`

Then iterate them and compare them with your custom compare function.
In this case I chose to emulate javascript with non null strings and not empty strings. Modify as you see fit.

```
public String sourceFilter(String... input) {
    for(String test : input) {
        if(test != null && !test.isEmpty()) {
            return test;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I don't know what the break even point is that the streams are more efficient in this case, but I'd imagine it would be a pretty high number to cover the initialization cost for it.